# /bin/bash: saved_model_cli: command not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am building some MLOP pipelines. I am using the sage-maker studio.    When I am trying to show all the saved model, `!saved_model_cli show --all --dir './model/tensorflow/saved_model/0/'` This gives me the error. The file './model/tensorflow/saved_model/0/ exist in my directory.
`/bin/bash: saved_model_cli: command not found`
What am I doing wrong?

my expectation is that to have get the answer, I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would begin by checking if saved_model_cli is installed. Assuming you are running TensorFlow here. This link has some useful information:

[Using the SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#running_a_savedmodel_in_tensorflow_serving)

Next I would check the permission on the folder (read / list etc).

Hope this helps.